# How to animate left bar menu in android (shrink effect)?

Tags: android, animation, menubar, google-tv

I have the following view:

```
------------------------------------
o Menu1 |   
@ Menu2 |
# Menu3 |         CONTENT
        |
        |
------------------------------------
```

And I want to create an animation that shrinks the menu bar to show just the icons like this:

```
------------------------------------
o |   
@ |
# |               CONTENT
  |
  |
------------------------------------
```

I already make the change work by applying Visibility.GONE to the text labels and resizing the LinearLayout that contains the menu but I want to animate that "shrinking" effect. I tried applying an scale animation along x but this doesn't work. Anybody already did something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should ideally use here is Left Navigation Bar. It allows you to put your Action items on the left.

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples#LeftNavBar

Check out Panoramio for an example of how to integrate it in your app. Its really simple.
Once thats done..for the animation effect use:

```
bar.setDisplayOptions(LeftNavBar.DISPLAY_AUTO_EXPAND);
bar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
```